# Unmarshal JSON in JSON in Go

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshal a JSON object where one field contains a JSON string into one coherent object. How do I do that in Go?

**Example:**

Input:

```json
{
  "foo":1,
  "bar":"{\\"a\\":\\"Hello\\"}"
}
```

Go type:

```golang
type Child struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
}

type Main struct {
    Foo int   `json:"foo"`
    Bar Child `json:"bar"`
}
```

I guess I'd need to implement a custom `UnmarshalJSON` implementation on one of the types, but its twisting my head to figure out on which one and how.

Comment: What is the result you're aiming for?

Comment: Set field Bar to type `string`, then unmarshal that itself again. Then build the struct separately if you want it as one struct.

Comment: The desired result is to marshal everything into one go struct “flattening” the json nesting. I thought the example would make that obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to treat this as if the JSON String were just part of the surrounding JSON object?  If so, then yes, as you suggest, a custom `UnmarshalJSON` method on `Child` should accomplish this.

```golang
func (c *Child) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    var jsonString string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &jsonString); err != nil {
        return err // Means the string was invalid
    }
    type C Child // A new type that doesn't have UnmarshalJSON method
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), (*C)(c))
}
```

[See it in the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/OwG3n9NcvKD)

Comment: Thanks. I’m curious why this doesn’t cause infinite recursion. I thought it could work like that but than got stuck on the thought that this should recurse and the second time it wouldn’t be a string.

Comment: @fahrradflucht: `type C Child` declares a new type, so it does not have the `UnmarshalJSON` method to cause recursion.

Answer (score 0):

if i were to create a custom `UnmarshalJson` for that data, I would create an auxiliary struct `auxMain` that has the same fields as the main struct but with `Bar` field as string. Then it unmarshals the JSON data into this auxiliary struct, extracting the `Foo` field and the `Bar` field as a string. After that, it unmarshals the Bar field as string into the `Child` struct, and assigns the extracted Foo field and the Child struct to the Main struct.

It's a round about way but seems to work in the playground.

```
func (m *Main) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    type auxMain struct {
        Foo int    `json:"foo"`
        Bar string `json:"bar"`
    }
    var a auxMain
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &a); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var child Child
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(a.Bar), &child); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    m.Foo = a.Foo
    m.Bar = child
    return nil
}
```

try it out in the PlayGround and see: https://go.dev/play/p/wWIceUxu1tj

Don't know if this is what you are looking for.